# Is there a memory leak in these functions?

Tags: c++

On valgrind it shows :

```
==87903== HEAP SUMMARY:
==87903==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 2 blocks
==87903==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 3 frees, 29 bytes allocated
==87903== 
==87903== LEAK SUMMARY:
==87903==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 2 blocks
```

```
char *m_name;
        int m_dob;
        int m_power;
        bool m_super;
        int m_level;
```

```
    void Saiyan::setEmpty()
    {
        m_name =nullptr;
        m_dob = 0;
        m_power = 0;
        m_super = false;

    }
    Saiyan::Saiyan(const char* name, int dob, int power)

    {   setEmpty();
        set(name, dob, power); 
    }

    //Checks paramater
    void Saiyan::set(const char* name, int dob, int power, int level , bool super)
    {
        if (name==nullptr || strlen(name) == 0 || dob > 2020 || power < 0) {
            setEmpty();
        }
        else {
            m_name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
            strcpy(m_name, name);
            m_dob = dob;
            m_power = power;
            m_super = super;
            m_level = level;
        }
    }
```

should i delete before allocating new memory ,? Also will turning an int to a double cause any memory leak? I just started coding so it would be great if you could explain from a noob perspective.

**Problem solved , just clear memory before using it !!**

Comment: For every `new []` there must be a corresponding `delete []`. I don't see any `delete []` here. Therefore, there's a leak.

Comment: Note that *valgrind* has options to get more details on the memory leaks. Quite useful sometimes

Comment: Side note: If allowed by the assignment, use `std::string`. in place of the `char *`s. It does the memory management grunt-work for you.

Comment: Turning an `int` into a `double` won't cause any memory leakage, but you may lose some precision with larger numbers. [Some reading on that](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and many other floating point math related topics.

Comment: @FredLarson oh sorry, i kept it separate because i wanted to minimize the amount of code that is being posted. What i was trying to ask is that should i always use delete before initializing new

Comment: Also familiarize yourself with [The Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Unless you adequately protect that allocation, copying (accidentally or otherwise) an instance of `Saiyan` can turn into quite an adventure.